# Google OAuth 2.0 for Android missing client_secret and redirect_uri settings

Tags: android, google-oauth, google-developers-console

I'm following [this](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/native-app) tutorial to authenticate users.

Once I got the authorization, I would like to [exchange it for the token](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/native-app#exchange-authorization-code). However, for that, I need `client_secret` and `redirect_uri`. I cannot see anything in my console. I've found some old articles but none of them matched what I saw.

[image: Google Cloud Console > Client ID for Android]

I see only the above when I click [the link](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials) in [Create authorization credentials](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/native-app#creatingcred) and select **Create credentials > OAuth client ID > Android** (iOS is basically the same, no secret or URI options).

Google recommends its [OAuth library](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start), but it's in Java which is quite annoying if you want to have a multiplatform login.